# Destroy or sell? Avodah zarah?

Tags: avodah-zarah

I previously owned a rental and had a tenant who passed away. His family left Scientology fiction books and lectures by Ron Hubbard in my rental attic. These may be worth around $500 if I were to sell them.

Do I have to destroy them or can I sell them and profit (either keep the money or donate to Jewish charity) from these? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Mr. qxz! The more information you provide, the better your likelihood of getting a quality answer. So, perhaps you'd want to [edit] to explain what exactly it is that Scientology espouses which you think might be avodah zarah. (Expecting users to know what other philosophies believe is actually officially off-topic here.)